# selectize angular with angular md-input container

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, selectize.js

I'm searching to use md-input-container (https://material.angularjs.org/0.9.4/#/api/material.components.input/directive/mdInputContainer) with or selectize-ng or angular-selectize.

```
 <md-input-container md-theme="hs-green">
   <label class="label" for="brandsInput">Brands</label>
   <!-- <selectize id="brandsInput" name="brandsInput" required config="vm.brandsConfig" data-ng-model="vm.brands"></selectize> -->
   <input type="text" id="brandsInput" name="brandsInput"
                 selectize="vm.brandsConfig" data-ng-model="vm.brands" />

   <div data-ng-messages="signupStepOneForm.vatInput.$error" data-ng-show="signupStepOneForm.vatInput.$dirty">
     <div data-ng-message="required">Campo obbligatorio</div>
     <div data-ng-message="pattern">Partita IVA non valida</div>
   </div>
</md-input-container>
```

And this is my options for selectize:

```
vm.brandsConfig = {
  delimiter: '|',
  plugins: ['remove_button', 'restore_on_backspace'],
  create: true,
  openOnFocus: false,
  placeholder: 'Brands'
};
```

This code generates an input for selectize and a separate label. But components doesn't works like normal md-input-container.

Anyone try to do this?

Thanks